# How to add text Watermark in Agora android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, agora.io

Can anyone please help me with text Watermark in android agora broadcast live video? I tried with WatermarkOptions, but I can only add images, so can anyone tell me is it possible to show the text as Watermark in agora android broadcast live video.

Answer (score 0):

I never came across directly through agora android SDK but you can try on similar lines.
[Java API](https://docs.agora.io/en/Recording/recording_watermark_java?platform=Linux%20Java)